# Issue converting string to DateTime

Tags: c#, datetime

I have this string : `20190312T120000`  basically its a start event value in Icloud .ics file.

How can i convert :

`20190312T120000`   to `.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss")` format.

I am trying to use Try.Parse and ParseExact but no success.

Is there some built in way or do i have to do it manually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe the ICS date time(RFC 5545) has a built-in conversion in c#.

You can do the following.  First need to get it into a `Date` object.

```
var format = "yyyyMMddTHHmmssZ";
var icsDate = "20190312T120000 ";

var date = DateTime.ParseExact(dateString, format, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Now can put into formatted string;

```
var dateStr = date.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
```

Answer (score 2):

You can convert it to a `DateTime` using `ParseExact`:

```
var dateString = "20190312T120000";
var parsed = DateTime.ParseExact(dateString, "yyyyMMddTHHmmss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.AdjustToUniversal);
```

I've assumed that the date you're providing is UTC, but if it's local time then you should write the above as:

```
var dateString = "20190312T120000";
var parsed = DateTime.ParseExact(dateString, "yyyyMMddTHHmmss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.AssumeLocal);
```

This will assume that the date is in the machine executing the code's timezone.

You can then write it in your target format like so:

```
Console.WriteLine(parsed.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss"));
```

** Remember that `DateTime` objects do not have any format themselves - they store the date as a number of ticks, so you can only format a date when you convert it to a `string`.

[Try it online](https://rextester.com/ORX35054)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`DateTime.ParseExact()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.parseexact?view=netframework-4.7.2) to parse to a `DateTime`. The exact format string would be `yyyyMMddTHHmmss` ([Date and time string formats](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings)).

Then you can format the date in whatever way you like:

```
string datestring = "20190312T120000";
var dateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(datestring, "yyyyMMddTHHmmss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

Console.WriteLine(dateTime.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss"));

// output
03/12/2019 12:00:00
```